# Can I illustrate how a relationship depends on another in an ER diagram?

Tags: erd, database-diagrams

I'm new to data modelling and trying to build my first ER diagram for supermarket management. My current diagram is based on the following description which I myself come up with:

*"Suppliers supply products. After receiving products from suppliers, a supermarket employee will create a delivery note.*

*Customers purchase products and bring them to a supermarket employee. After receiving products from customers, that employee will raise an invoice."*

So, the problem is: Whether an employee write a delivery note or raise an invoice depends on from whom he receives the products. Is there any way to display this in my ER diagram?

[image]